# Select within a select FROM error while trying to work out average

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, average

I have the tables:

---

### Review

- Product_ID (FK for Product_ID on Product table)
- Recommendation
- Quality (FK for Score_ID on Score table)
- Value (FK for Score_ID on Score table)

---

### Score

- Score_ID
- Value
- Description

---

### Product

- Product_ID
- Name
- Price

---

### Subcategory

- SubCat_ID
- Name

---

### ProductSubcategory

- Product_ID (FK for Product_ID on Product table)
- SubCat_ID (FK for SubCat_ID on Subcategory table)

My aim is to create a query that returns the average quality and value of a product that is in the '4K Ultra HD TVs' subcategory, and the price is more than $4000. I can't just return the Score_ID, I need to return the average of the value (which is a field in the Score table).

I have been working on this for hours and this is what I have come up with. However, I do not know how to fix the error. I believe it has something to do with the AVG function in the subquery, or the way I have used SELECT.

```
COLUMN PID FORMAT 999
COLUMN AVG_QUALITY FORMAT 99999999999
COLUMN AVG_VALUE FORMAT 99999999999

SELECT  R.PRODUCT_ID AS PID,
        AVG_QUALITY = (SELECT AVG(SQU.SCORE_VALUE)
        FROM SCORE SQU
        INNER JOIN SCORE SQU ON SQU.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_QUALITY
        WHERE R.SCORE_QUALITY = SQU.SCORE_ID),
        AVG_VALUE = (SELECT AVG(SVA.SCORE_VALUE)
        FROM SCORE SVA
        INNER JOIN SCORE SVA ON SVA.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_VALUE
        WHERE R.SCORE_VALUE = SVA.SCORE_ID)
FROM REVIEW R
INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_ID = R.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTSUBCATEGORY PS ON PS.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN SUBCATEGORY S ON S.SUBCAT_ID = PS.SUBCAT_ID
WHERE S.NAME = '4K Ultra HD TVs'
AND P.PRICE > 4000;
```

```
        AVG_QUALITY = (SELECT AVG(SQU.SCORE_VALUE)
                    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Comment: . . Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, put the query into the question as *text*, not an image.  That makes it much simpler for others to understand it.

Comment: Hint: Why is your first line not `SELECT PID = R.PRODUCT_ID`?

Comment: @melpomene . . . Downvoting is not really in the spirit of helping a new contributor.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why not?

Comment: To the best of my recollection, I think you are confusing with SQL Server (or other DBMS). IN Oracle, you do not assign a value to a variable within a select (tyhis is what @melpomene meant in his comment).

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing at `=`, not `AVG` or the subselect.

It looks like you're trying to give your selected values names. The syntax for that is not `NAME = EXPR`, but `EXPR AS NAME` (like in your first column, `R.PRODUCT_ID AS PID`).

Thus

```
    AVG_QUALITY = (SELECT AVG(SQU.SCORE_VALUE)
    FROM SCORE SQU
    INNER JOIN SCORE SQU ON SQU.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_QUALITY
    WHERE R.SCORE_QUALITY = SQU.SCORE_ID)
```

should say

```
    (SELECT AVG(SQU.SCORE_VALUE)
    FROM SCORE SQU
    INNER JOIN SCORE SQU ON SQU.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_QUALITY
    WHERE R.SCORE_QUALITY = SQU.SCORE_ID)
        AS AVG_QUALITY
```

Comment: I updated it to your code, but now this error comes up:
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

I also updated the AVG_VALUE to match your logic

Comment: @carrybag94 Which column is it talking about?

Comment: @carrybag94 The whole `INNER JOIN SCORE SQU ON SQU.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_QUALITY` line makes no sense and should be removed.

Comment: ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 0):

So I just reformatted your query for (my personal) readability and changed the way aliases are assigned:

```
SELECT R.PRODUCT_ID AS PID
  , (   SELECT AVG(SQU.SCORE_VALUE)
        FROM SCORE AS SQU       -- This is SQU
        INNER JOIN SCORE AS SQU -- This is SQU
            ON SQU.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_QUALITY
        WHERE R.SCORE_QUALITY = SQU.SCORE_ID) AS AVG_QUALITY
  , (   SELECT AVG(SVA.SCORE_VALUE)
        FROM SCORE AS SVA       -- This is SVA
        INNER JOIN SCORE AS SVA -- This is SVA
            ON SVA.SCORE_ID = R.SCORE_VALUE
        WHERE R.SCORE_VALUE = SVA.SCORE_ID) AS AVG_VALUE
FROM REVIEW AS R
INNER JOIN PRODUCT AS P
    ON P.PRODUCT_ID = R.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTSUBCATEGORY AS PS
    ON PS.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN SUBCATEGORY AS S
    ON S.SUBCAT_ID = PS.SUBCAT_ID
WHERE S.NAME = '4K Ultra HD TVs'
AND P.PRICE > 4000;
```

Issue is that in each subquery you use same table twice and you create exactly the same alias twice and that makes your database panic. I've left a comment in code showing exact places.

So just create aliases that are unique within your query and you'll be sound.

Comment: ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis